# Android Phonegap Scroll not work

Tags: android, html, cordova

i developed an android app by using html5 and phonegap (cordova 2.7.0); it's an application for image search, use the google API.
Returns a list of images that start with a tap.

It works perfectly on almost all devices, but on small screens with Android 2.3.x, scrolling (or click on image) does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually its not an issue with small screens. Its an issue with the webview in Droid 2.3. You wont notice this in Droid 4.x +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run into an android [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6864). Overflowing DIVs inside BODY tag wont allow you to scroll. Same bug was there in iPhone (iOS < 5), but there atleast you could use two fingers and scroll.

However there are workarounds for it. You can use third party libraries such as [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4), touchScroll ...

iScroll will disable your inputs for the div which you have applied scroll to. If its a simple paragraph use iScroll.

[Reference](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/scroll-div.htm)

Comment: ok thanks, overflow problem solved.

But there remains the problem of click on the image, does not work on Android 2.3.x. 

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: @user2726314 Which scroll plugin did you use ? If its [this one](http://chris-barr.com/2010/05/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/) then you need to comment out the `event.preventDefault()` line in the first listener.

Comment: after a lot of test we noted that the problem is hashchange event.is there a way to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While 2-Stroker's answer is the correct one here is a quick and dirty solution, add a few `<br>` tags at the end. Worked for me ;)

Comment: added 
dinamically ( $.().append ) and didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through the trouble of adding iScroll you can also use:

```
// Workaround for problematic scrolling behaviour on Android
// we can't fix this in css directly as it breaks iOS and the
// platform selector in css is unreliable
if ( device.platform === 'Android' ) {
    $('.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile .ui-page, .ui-mobile [data-role="page"], .ui-mobile [data-role="dialog"], .ui-page, .ui-mobile .ui-page-active ').css("position", "initial");
}
```